# What is the DQL Equivalent of MySQL's FOUND_ROWS() Method?

Tags: mysql, orm, doctrine, dql

Is there any method or technique for getting the number of results from a `select` query as if it had been run without a `limit` clause using DQL? This behavior would be similar to using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()` in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. There is [Paginator extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions#paginator) for Doctrine versions **lower than 2.2**. **Starting with version 2.2** Doctrine ships with a [Paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) for DQL queries out of the box.

Using non-standard DB features (like `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`) is not good practice with Doctrine (or other DBAL). Doctrine hides all DB-dependent circumstances from user. So you can't think about using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` with Doctrine until it's not a part of cross-database SQL.

Comment: I don't see how one would get total records amount as if one was executing `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.